# MDX query running slow, but only in certain arrangement

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, cube

I am programmaticly generating a MDX query in the following format:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[MTD] AS
        SUM ({[Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2011-11-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2011-11-30T00:00:00]
        * {[Dimension1].[Dimension1].[Val1]}
        * {[Dimension2].[Dimension2].[Val2]}
        * {[Dimension3].[Dimension3].[Val3]}
        * {{[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[XXXX],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[DBS],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[FD],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[GSCFDASIA],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[FDEM],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[DX],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[OSWP],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[OOO],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[CFD]}}
        * {-{[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[SELI],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[SELE],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[MRDN],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[WCSG],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[NEWB],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[VASS]}}
        }, [Measures].[Trade Count])
```

As you can see, it's a simple way to create an intersection of dimensional values, and it has been working great for some time.

Recently i rewrote the cube from using a single dimension table with many attributes, to using a separate table for each dimension (for processing performance reasons)

The problem, is that when i filter by Dimension4 and Dimension5 together, it is all of a sudden really slow! if i comment out dimension4 and 5, the query takes a second.. if i un-comment Dimension4 query takes 40 seconds.. if i then un-comment Dimension5 line, the query takes 8 minutes.

the dimension is joined to the measure by ID field (int)

the dimension has 238 values

if i do a simple query:

select count on Columns, {-{[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[SELI],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[SELE],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[MRDN],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[WCSG],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[NEWB],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[VASS]}} on rows from MyCube

the query takes sub second. It is something about having a combination of dimensions (up top) that is making it so painfully slow. No idea how to troubleshoot it.

something that may be worth noting, is that my cube has 13 partitions, and i have not set up "partition aggregation" step while setting up partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I got my query to process in 6 minutes (from 3.5 hours).

2 things allowed me to optimize it this way:

**1. Use Month/Year members in Date Range instead of Dates** 
Before:

```
SUM ({[Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2011-11-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2011-11-30T00:00:00]
```

After

```
SUM ({[Time].[Month].&[2011-11-01T00:00:00]
```

This was huge. Since OLAP treats each date member as a separate entity, it cross joins all the dates in the range, with all other filters. In my case, i wanted a full month, or full year, so there was no need for a date range.

**2. Put all common filters (in all the members) into common WHERE clause**

In my case, i had quite a few members sharing the same filters. Simply putting them into the bottom of the query,  sped things up another 40%.

In the end, my query went from 4 hours, to 6.5 minutes. I can further speed it up by adding appropriate aggregations in my cube definition. but didn't get to that part yet.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this version ? :

```
 WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[MTD] AS
    SUM ({[Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2011-11-01T00:00:00]:[Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2011-11-30T00:00:00]
    * {{[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[XXXX],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[DBS],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[FD],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[GSCFDASIA],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[FDEM],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[DX],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[OSWP],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[OOO],[Dimension4].[Dimension4].[CFD]}}
    * {-{[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[SELI],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[SELE],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[MRDN],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[WCSG],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[NEWB],[Dimension5].[Dimension5].[VASS]}}
    }, ([Measures].[Trade Count],[Dimension1].[Dimension1].[Val1],[Dimension2].[Dimension2].[Val2],[Dimension3].[Dimension3].[Val3])  )
```

The - sign before [Dimension5] it's a mistake ?

It's making the crossjoin a bit smaller and putting single values in the tuple. Good questions if this improves performance.

Comment: the sign - indicates that the values should be excluded. (sort of like "not in" in sql)

Comment: Was new to me. Is 'All' all values of hierarchy [Dimension5] (including [All] member) of all levels ?

Comment: still trying to figure out what you did there :) .. so basically you add every other dimension into that final set? because my example was simplified.. i have about 10-20 of these lines starting with *.. i just narrowed it down to that one dimension making a huge impact on time

Comment: no, I included all dimension defined with a single member in the measure tuple. This should make easier not only the crossjoin but the evaluation of the measure (you already know you're doing a sum in a subcube).

Comment: ok i tried this approach, and as i am adding dimensions into the bottom set, the query takes longer and longer...